# How can I fix it to show the total number of posts by user in the result list?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

As a premise, the membership bulletin board is functioning, and the total of keywords such as "delicious" and "bad" in the posted content of the logged-in user can be acquired and displayed with the following code. Would you please teach me where to modify to list the total number of keywords posted by all authenticated users?

#### Web.php:

```
Route::get('/myfood', 'HomeController@myfood')->name('home.myfood');
Route::get('/foods', 'HomeController@foods')->name('home.foods');
```

#### Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function myfood()
    {
        $user = auth()->user()->id;
        $myusers=User::where('id', $user)->get();
        $PostsOisiCount = Post::where('user_id', $user)->where(function($query) {$query->where('body', 'like', '%delicious%')
            ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%bad%');})->count();
        $PostsCount = Post::where('user_id', $user)->count();
        return view('myfood', compact('user', 'myusers', 'PostsOisiCount', 'PostsCount'));
    }
    public function foods()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $PostsOisiCount = Post::where('body', 'like', '%delicious%')
            ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%bad%')
            ->count();
        $PostsCount = Post::count();
        return view('foods', compact('users', 'PostsOisiCount', 'PostsCount'));
    }
}
```

#### myfoodBlade:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Results</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($myusers as $myuser)
            <tr>
                <th>{{$myuser->id}}</th>
                <td>{{$myuser->name}}</td>
                <td>
                    ($PostsOisiCount / $PostsCount ) * 100
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### foodsBlade:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Results</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <th>{{$user->id}}</th>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>
                    ($PostsOisiCount / $PostsCount ) * 100
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would start off with using [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships), so that each user has it's own post collection. You can then query that to get the count.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the code. We have a list of posts for everyone and a list of posts for logged-in users, but if you know it, it would be helpful if you could get a sample code.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to help you but first lets make your code more performant:

When you want to do a `count` on a Model, you don't need to do `->get()->count()` as that is getting the data from the database (`->get()`) and that could be HUGE, even running out of memory, and then counting the array values (`->count()`). Instead of doing that, you can directly count on the database and the database will always do this way faster than any language. So your could would be: `$total = Model::conditions()->count()`, `$total` will directly have a positive (or `0`) integer number, and that's it!

Your code should be like:

```php
$users = User::all();
$PostsOisiCount = Post::where('user_id', $users)->where('body', 'like', '%delicious%')->orWhere('body', 'like', '%bad%')->count();
$PostsCount = Post::where('user_id', $users)->count();
```

Have in mind that you are not currently getting the Logged in User's data, but EVERYONE data, because you are doing `User::all()`, so you will get all IDs that are not soft deleted. Instead of doing that, you can still get everything by removing `where('user_id', $users)`:

```php
$PostsOisiCount = Post::where('body', 'like', '%delicious%')->orWhere('body', 'like', '%bad%')->count();
$PostsCount = Post::count();
```

---

To be able to just get data from `authenticated` Users, that is absolutely way more complex than it seems and it depends a lot on your Authentication "driver"... Where are you storing or tracking sessions? If they are logged in, what should you read? So this is very dependant on your authentication implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's a big help.
I'm still a beginner, so the membership bulletin board I made is almost the same as the textbook.
I don't understand the question perfectly, so the answer may be wrong.
The authentication function is generated by the following command and is not customized.

composer require laravel / ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

You've heard about the session, should I supplement the controller and blade files? I'll supplement the code in the question.

I would like to be able to display the list even if there are logged-in users. Is this possible?

Comment: By the way, if I removed the extra code as I just learned, I couldn't see the total number of extracted keywords. All counts are 0.

Comment: @chupi I am sorry, I did not even look at your Blade file. It is 0 because I removed the `$user`, from the second example. But still, be careful, you are getting ALL users. Imagine if you have 1 Million users, PHP will not be able to handle it so you will need to get [chunks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results). Related to your authentication driver, it is more complicated. I am not sure right now what you should do, as I would need to check how it works (I do not remember by memory), but I still think that is way harder to do, but no imposible.

Comment: Thank you for telling us about chunks. That helps a lot. If it becomes difficult to display a list of all users, for example, since the total number of logged-in users is acquired in another blade file, is it possible to acquire each and display a list of all users? I want to complete anything, so I would be grateful if you could give me some hints or advice.

Comment: If you already know how to specifically get all **LOGGED IN** users, please update your question with that code and I can update mine to try to help you. Else, you can just get all users and you are doing in your blade.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That helps a lot! I edited the question. Added root, controller and blade files. Is there enough information to get your advice?